# Dynamic return type in templated method in c++03

Tags: c++

Recently I've been tasked with rewriting some of my code from C++14 to C++03 so that I can make use of [ompSs](https://pm.bsc.es/ompss). However, I'm not sure if this particular snippet of code can be rewritten without making use of `auto`.

I have a template class `Field< Type >` which is a container for `Type`. The method from the snippet defines the behavior of the summation of two fields, as the sum of every entry in the field point by point.

`Type`, can be either a `double`, or a self designed class `Vector`. The 
behaviour of `Vector + Vector`, `Vector + double`, and `double + Vector`, are fully defined in the definition of class `Vector`.

The code snippet is able to fully define the intended behaviour for the 
summation of `Field`s in it's four possible scenarios:

- `Field< double > + Field< Vector >`,
- `Field< Vector > + Field< double >`,
- `Field< double > + Field< double >`,
- `Field< Vector > + Field< Vector >`

This is accomplished by creating a `response` `Field`, where `Type` is inferred by the result of the summation of the first element of both vectors.

How can I accomplish the same thing without making use of the awesome `auto` 
operator?

```
template< typename Type_1, typename Type_2 > const auto operator+ (
const Field< Type_1 >& lhs, const Field< Type_2 >& rhs ) {

    auto response = Field <
       typename std::remove_const<decltype( lhs.get(0) + rhs.get(0) )>::type
    >( lhs.size() );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lhs.size(); i++ ){
        response[i] = lhs.get(i) + rhs.get(i);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you are out of luck here. The problem is mainly that you can't select a particular overload of `operator+` without also specifying the return type, so you can't retrieve it independently in C++03.

What you can do, however, is to write a meta-function that gives the correct return type. If you use this function also to define the `operator+` overloads you'll get the same compile-time guarantees and nice-enough errors:

```
template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
struct AddResult;

template <>
struct AddResult<Vector, Vector> { typedef Vector result_type; }
// ...

typename AddResult<Vector, Vector>::result_type operator+(Vector lhs, Vector rhs)
// ...

template< typename Type_1, typename Type_2 >
Field<typename AddResult<Type_1, Type_2>::result_type>
operator+ (const Field<Type_1>& lhs, const Field<Type_2>& rhs)
{
    Field<typename AddResult<Type_1, Type_2>::result_type> response(lhs.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i != lhs.size(); i++) {
        response[i] = lhs.get(i) + rhs.get(i);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Very far from being pretty, but I can't think of a nicer solution.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will try your solution after the other proposed solution, since the other one looks prettier.

Comment: okay, I'm trying to implement your solution, but I'm having some problems. 
`typename AddResult<Vector, Vector>::result_type operator+(Vector lhs, Vector rhs)` won't this classh with my own definition of the operator + between vectors and vectors?

Comment: OK! this worked! Thank you very much!, I did have to make some changes in the code.the 3rd block of code was not necessary, and i had to remove some typenames from the main function. Could you please go through my final code and see if i did something stupid? http://fiddle.jyt.io/github/ae8171afba2dd5d980053485ee176124

Comment: @pupo162: don't return const object. You should probably check that both size are equal.

Comment: The third block was just meant to be an indication of what to do with your actual `operator+` implementations (i.e. use the same type). I agree with @Jarod42, that the implementation should not return a `const`, it was only  to be in line with the existing implementation (as was the code style ...)

Comment: @Jarod42 "You should probably check that both size are equal." You are correct. I'm already doing that (plus a few other things) but i removed them for the sake of a minimalistic example.

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace auto with an explicit type. 
In this case, you can add a template parameter (to the front of the template so that Type1 and Type2 can still be deduced), and specify the result type at the call site.

```
template<typename Result, typename Type_1, typename Type_2 > 
const Result operator+ ( const Field< Type_1 >& lhs, const Field< Type_2 >& rhs ) ...
```

Comment: I think this solution would be ideal. would it work if i did something like:

    Field< double > f1;

    Field< double > f2;

    Field< double > f3;

    f1 = f2 + f3

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not seem to work with the error "couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Result’", when used in above mentioned test case.

Comment: That is a known limitation of this, you have to annotate the call site with the return type.

Comment: For my project, I think it's preferable  to have a dirtier solution in the method definition than in the method call. As such I went with the other proposed solution. Thank you for your response anyway, will keep it in the back of my head for other occasions!

Comment: Having non deducing type for operator makes operator mostly not usable:
`f1 = f2.operator+<T1>(f3);`...